# How do I get the Joomla Framework Files for a production server?

Tags: installation, git, joomla-framework

Following the "simple" instructions, I'm completely unable to get the FrameWork to function.  I don't normally use Git *or* Composer, so don't know what to expect as a final result when these 4 steps are complete to even begin troubleshooting.  Some of the Git files are upwards of 3 years old, so I'm not even sure if any of this is current or not.

Even when I get something installed, I see a `www\` folder that has a few files in it, which I presume go into the root of my site, but they appear to have dependencies on folders above that folder, so suggests to me that I have to have these folders on my production server, or that the installation process hasn't complete.

Ultimately, I just want to get to the folders/files that I need in order to use the Joomla Framework (on a production server) can I get those somewhere easily, or is there something missing in what I'm doing below?

https://framework.joomla.org/

> **Get the Sample Application**
>
> The easiest way to get to know the Joomla! Framework is to start with
>   the sample app.
>
> ```
> Install Composer.
> Download this [sample app][1] repository from GitHub.
> Run `composer install`.
> View in your browser.
> ```

**Result of "Run composer install":**

```
Basic usage: composer <command>
For more information just type "composer".

D:\www\framework-app-master>composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
  - Installing psr/log (dev-master 5144da9)
    Cloning 5144da9525d24346bf009ff28f10cbaa1f0f166e

  - Installing joomla/framework (1.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v2.4.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing twbs/bootstrap (v2.3.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing twig/twig (v1.14.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing filp/whoops (1.0.9)
    Loading from cache

joomla/framework suggests installing symfony/yaml (Install symfony/yaml 2.* if you require YAML support.)
Generating autoload files
> App\Setup\InstallScript::postInstall
Script App\Setup\InstallScript::postInstall handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception


  [ErrorException]
  symlink(): Could not fetch file information(error 3)


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]

D:\www\framework-app-master>
```

**Run "View in your browser"** (at localhost/framework-app-master/www/index.php)

```
Unable to handle request for route `index.php`.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`symlink` command for Bootstrap assets is failing. Symlinking is known not to work on some Windows versions.

> **Note:** Windows users should note that this function will only work if the system you run PHP from is Windows Vista/Windows Server 2008 or newer. Windows versions prior to that do not support symbolic links.

Don't know which OS you have, but if it's Windows and Vista or up, then it could be bug in PHP. It had some bugs with symlinking in 5.3.

All in all, to fix it:

Remove

```
"post-install-cmd": [
     "App\\Setup\\InstallScript::postInstall"
]
```

from `composer.json`.

Then run `composer install` again to finish installing all necessary dependencies.

Finally copy bootstrap assets from `../../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/docs/assets` to `www/assets` manually.

Double check that you have `App/Config/config.json` file, if not copy and create (or rename) it from `App/Config/config.dist.json`.